# value is becoming false in contextAPI in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux, react-hooks

I have to send values as `true` or `false` to another component in react.

so in my `A` component I am writing.

```
  <Name.Provider value={true}>
        </Name.Provider>
```

and in my `B` component I am writing

```
                            <Name.Consumer>
                            {
                            
                               value => 
                                  <span className="badge badge-white">
                                   {value && <Link to="user"> List of Users</Link>} 
                                 </span>
                            }
                          </Name.Consumer>
```

since I am passing `true` to `B`, it should display the `List of Users` , but it is not displaying.
could you please tell me what wrong I am doing?

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide that value to the link, I don't see in your code where are you providing that value, but you can have a look at this blog posts: 
https://kentcdodds.com/blog/how-to-use-react-context-effectively 
https://dmitripavlutin.com/react-context-and-usecontext/